# Angular need to move working code into a partial or something to display under other page html

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-template

I have a Angular SPA in which things are working fine except that the business wants me to move the code from this  link-group.html (which has its own controller, module etc..)

The URL with the code to put into a template or place the code underneath the other html code  supervisors.html

**URL for News that is in link-group.html that I need to move:**

```
http://localhost:1337/doc-home/#/tips/2?paginatePage=1
```

**File:**

```
link-group.html
```

**Location:**

[image]

Then the location of where I needs to display (move to)

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:1337/doc-home/#/supervisors
```

**File:**

```
supervisors.html
```

**Location:**

[image]

**Template?**  **controller reference?**

**UPDATE**

I want to take all the code from the link.group.html and move it to the supervisor.html page

However, there is specific code that is referring to the controller/module/database that is based on the URL

```
<div class="links-group" ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-show="!group.hidden">


<div ng-show="!edit" style="margin: 5px 0;">
<h3>{{ group.title }}</h3>
```

```
<div ng-show="edit === true">
<input style="margin: 5px 0" placeholder="title..." class="input" ng-model="group.title" />
```

---

**UPDATE 2  per suggestion from OP**

Current controller.js for supervisor.html

```
angular.module('supervisors')
 .controller('SupervisorsCtrl',

  function ($scope, UserService) {
      UserService.get(function (err, user) {
      $scope.user = user;
  });

});
```

So in order to modify can I add another module underneath it?

```
 angular.module('supervisors')
 .controller('SupervisorsCtrl',

  function ($scope, UserService) {
      UserService.get(function (err, user) {
      $scope.user = user;
  });

});

angular.module('linkgroup', ['ng'])
     .directive('linkgroup', function({{ dependencies of your controller here }}) {
return {
    templateUrl: {{ url of the template, likely link-group.html }},
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
        // think of this as the controller of a directive
        {{ code of your controller, 
           replace `this` with `$scope` if you used ControllerAs }}
    }
 };
});
```

Seems that there is NO module.js in the common folder, there is a directives.js and controller.js 
However I see that with links folder there is this code

```
angular.module('links')

.controller('LinksCtrl', function ($scope, LinksService, SearchService, UserService, notify, $window, $location) {

$scope.message = "";

UserService.get(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        notify.error('Error getting current user.');
    } else {
        if (user.groups.WEB_ESO !== true) {
            $location.path('/');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: What is your problem exactly besides you probably need to do some refactoring?

Comment: I need to display all the html from link-group.html RIGHT underneath the html on supervisors.html.   I cannot simply copy and paste as that code from link.group.html has specific angular code directives and repeat loop etc.. that is from the module and controller for link.group.html   so I wish to move the code into a partial template view or whatever is easiest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could get away with a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that contains your `link-group`. Transformation is pretty straightforward (if you used `$scope` in your controller it's almost direct copy+paste):

```javascript
angular.module('linkgroup', ['ng'])
.directive('linkgroup', function({{ dependencies of your controller here }}) {
    return {
        templateUrl: {{ url of the template, likely link-group.html }},
        link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            // think of this as the controller of a directive
            {{ code of your controller, 
               replace `this` with `$scope` if you used ControllerAs }}
        }
    };
});
```

Then in `supervisors.html` add `<linkgroup></linkgroup>` at the bottom.

Comment: Interesting.  I was reading about  ng-view and  ng-include  , would you recommend against those?

Comment: You could probably achieve the same with those, but it lacks clarity. Directives provide a reuseable element that has all its functionality attached to it (you won't find 3rd-party controllers, but 3rd-party directives are common). Like a webcomponent or ReactJS element or Angular2 component. All go the way directives started. So I won't try to mimick this behavior and instead just use it.

Comment: Ok I was even thinking about the whole ng-controlller with a path to the controller.    I wish to implement what you are saying, I'm going to do another Update to my question   Thanks in advance